# Why don’t “snow” and “plow” — well, or “plough” — rhyme?

Tags: etymology, pronunciation, orthography, old-english, historical-change

They (sometimes?) have the same ending when spelt but don’t rhyme when said.  Why is that?

Comment: They do not have the same ending. Spelling is always a compromise and an approximation, it is spoken language that is primary. And in spoken English they obviously have a different ending. Which in turn makes sense as they are two completely different and unrelated words. At the same time, [eye rhyme](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eye_rhyme) is actually a thing.

Comment: Old English, which was phonemic, has *plóh* or actually *plóġ* for the first, and *snáw* for the second.  Why you think that *snáw* and *plóġ* ought to rhyme I have no idea.  Remember that ***Modern English spelling does not reflect its modern pronunciation.*** It at best reflects the pronunciation of Middle English prior to the Great Vowel Shift. So these are all silly questions, thems that try to link spelling and pronunciation in English. It just isn’t there, so please stop looking for it.

Comment: Because English. That's why.

Comment: Patrick87 put that as an answer and I'll mark it as the answer in a heart beat!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe because they don't always have the same ending http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/british/plough_1?q=plough

Comment: Or rather, because it is pronunciation that is spelled and not spelling that is pronounced.

Comment: RegDwigHt you just blew my mind